# Jolt transformation to append a json to existing array

Tags: java, json, jolt

[image: Success Response Case]

[image: Failure Response Case]

I have a written a jolt transformation to transform an API response.

The Input is

```json
{
  "sample": {
    "numbers": [
      {
        "id1": "number1",
        "id2": "1",
        "levels": {
          "id3": "level3"
        }
      },
      {
        "id1": "number2",
        "id2": "2",
        "levels": {
          "id3": "level-test"
        }
      }
    ],
    "extra": [
      {
        "id1": "extra1",
        "id2": "extra2",
        "plans": {
          "id3": "first-plan",
          "unit": "2"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}

For Failure scenario input is

    {
    "code": "NOT_VALID",
    "message": "Invalid Request",
    "httpStatus": "400"
    }
```

The jolt transformation is

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "sample": {
        "numbers": {
          "*": {
            "id1": "numbers[&1].id1",
            "id2": "numbers[&1].id2",
            "levels": {
              "id3": "numbers[&2].id3"
            }
          }
        },
        "#true": "success"
      },
      "message": "errorMessage",
      "code": {
        "#false": "success"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

The expected Output is

```json
{
  "success": "true",
  "numbers": [
    {
      "id1": "number1",
      "id2": "1",
      "id3": "level3"
    },
    {
      "id1": "number2",
      "id2": "2",
      "id3": "level-test"
    },
    {
      "id1": "extra1",
      "id2": "extra2",
      "id3": "first-plan"
    }
  ]
}
```

The output which I am able to get right now is

```json
{
  "success": "true",
  "numbers": [
    {
      "id1": "number1",
      "id2": "1",
      "id3": "level3"
    },
    {
      "id1": "number2",
      "id2": "2",
      "id3": "level-test"
    }
  ]
}
```

I am not able to figure out how extra array fields (id1, id2, plans.id3) will be appended to numbers array after all the elements of that array are transversed.

The Desired failure response should be

```
{
"errorMessage": "Invalid Request",
"success": "false"
}
```

Any Idea how it can be achieved.

Answer (score 1):

You can use following **shift** transformation specs

```json
[
  {
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "*": { //represents top level object's key name("sample")
        "*": { //represents both "numbers" and "extra"
          "*": {
            "id*": "&2[&1].&", // all keys starting with "id", and their values(".&") nested under common key and sub-key pairs such as "numbers[0]", "numbers[1]", "extra[0]"
            "levels|plans": {
              "id*": "&3[&2].&"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  {
   // remove object key names while adding extra attribute "success"
    "operation": "shift",
    "spec": {
      "#true": "success",
      "*": {
        "*": "numbers"
      }
    }
  }
]
```

the ***demo*** is on the site **http://jolt-demo.appspot.com/** :

[image]

Comment: Here for success cases, it will work but for failure cases, it will give array as null and the success field will also remain true, which ideally should be false

Comment: @Aditya Well, but where can I get whether success is false or true, there's no such info within the input.

Comment: I have updated the question and added the failure case as well

Comment: @Aditya Can you combine the newly provided stuff in only one input, and only one output as in the original question ?

Comment: Basically , if the API is giving correct response then the first input has to be modified and when the API is giving failure response then the failure one should run. The transformation that I have provided in the question gives both responses as output.

Comment: Assume that we get failure response, then what would be the input , can you edit considering this fact? Combine under one common input JSON value please @Aditya

Comment: The failure case incput is {
"code": "NOT_VALID",
"message": "Invalid Request",
"httpStatus": "400"
}, I have also added that in the first input of the question also.

Comment: Excuse me, it's incomplete, yet. Well, please embed that object  `{ "code": "NOT_VALID", "message": "Invalid Request", "httpStatus": "400" }` into the original input as an object or a list with the desired key name if exists any in order to construct a unique, valid JSON value. Btw, `the expected output` still remains the same as in the former case @Aditya

Comment: they don't come together. If the API gives successful response they it will work but for failure scenario it will not give desired response I am also adding the Jolt Demo screenshots in the question to show the success and failure cases.